# Incremental Load Process - Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All,

Thanks in advance for the assistance and guidance.

So...
We have been using snowflake for around a year now and have had a minor bug that we now need to tackle. Its not so much a bug but an improvement in our process.

We largely work with JSONS (large contestant volumes), we have a stream in a staging table where the JSON lands from Kafka, we have views that sit on top of the stream that break out the JSONs into a relational views. These views are then inserted into tables. This is all done using a single procedure that can do merges, insert only or even truncate then insert operations. This all works fine unless there is an issue with the JSON (missing data effecting the view for example) when this happens the procedure dumps the stream into a table. This results in anywhere between 1 and 10,000 JSONs dumped into our error table. The error might only originate from 1 jsons. What I would like is a secondary process to kick off that when the bulk load into the table has failed then the same logic is iterated though each JSON so that only the actual JSON that has errors is then written to our error table.

in SQL SERVER integration studios I would be able to have a insert source onject that was a bulk load then another object after that was an incremental load and then the errors from that would be written out to a table. I am after something like this.

Any suggestions, pointers would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: In your stored procedure, you can use an `if` block to check success of the bulk insert. If it fails, you can execute an `else` block that checks each file's JSON using `CHECK_JSON( <string_or_variant_expr> )`. You can then insert a row into an errors table for each one that fails this check.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The Check JSON function as far as I understand just checks that it is a valid JSON, due to going through KAFKA that has already been done. We have a selection of views that sit ontop of the JSON stream that transforms it and for many reasons the VIEWS can fail or the MERGE into the target can fail due to duplicated. Do you have any thoughts in that scenario?

Comment: If the views or merge fail, that will be a trappable SQL error. You can run the SELECT from the view or the MERGE inside a `try` block in JavaScript. If the statement produces a SQL error, it will immediately skip to the `catch` block for error handling.

Comment: So this is what we are doing already, the view fails we trap the error then write the stream out to an error table. The problem is that the stream might have 10,000 jsons in it of which only 1 is in correct.